# Difficulty running .net MQ application

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, windows-server-2003, filenotfoundexception, mq

Hi I am having the following error when I run the a .NET app

```
D:\Program Files\AscentSS\AscentSV\Staging\SimplePut>SimplePut -q ESB.BAT1.SERVICES.KOFAX.DOC.METADATA -h 10.49.97.31 -p 1417 -l BLI1.KOFAX.CLIENT
Start of SimplePut Application

Exception caught: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'amqmdnet, Version=7.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'amqmdnet, Version=7.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97'
   at SimplePut.SimplePut.PutMessages()
   at SimplePut.SimplePut.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\youngj\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SimplePut\SimplePut.cs:line 102

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Sample execution FAILED!

End of SimplePut Application
```

However, the file with the same public token does exist:

```
D:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v
7.0A\bin\sn" -T amqmdnet.dll

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 3.5.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key token is dd3cb1c9aae9ec97
```

Any ideas? App was compiled on x64 Win7.  Trying to run it on x32 Win2003 server. Thanks.

Comment: Fyi, full 7.5.0.1 MQ client is installed.

Comment: Try copying `amqmdnet.dll` to `system32` and `syswow64`

Answer (score 1):

MQs .NET layer isnt one dll, it is a number of them (amqmdxcs, amqmdnet, amqmdmsg etc) - especially since about 7.0.1. Have you actually installed the MQ server/client software or did you try to deploy an application with a reference to MQ and expect it to deploy with the MQ parts included?

Try running your code on a machine with the MQ product properly installed - if 7.1 or higher, you need to make it primary (defaults to being) in order to get the MQ parts registered in the GAC, or you need a config file pointing to what the MQ dlls are on the file system. Take a look at Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base and try to get the basic samples working first.

If all else fails, do what the instructios tell you and enable logging and see what it shows :-)